# Short URL with htaccess on many subfolders with same file

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this situation:
There are many scripts that can be accessed like this:
`http://website.com/script1/`
`http://website.com/script2/`

Each script has a `display.php` file that receives a variable from the `index.php` file VIA a link. I'm using the `$_GET` method to reat that variable.

Example:

`http://website.com/script1/display.php?id=124`

What I'm trying to do is to access the display page like this:

`http://website.com/script1/124`

`http://website.com/script2/124`

Does anyone have any suggestions? My experience with htaccess is ~0.

Comment: is id always number?

Comment: Yes, it's always a number. The `index.php` inserts some data into a SQL database, then passes the ID to the `display.php` file. The `display.php` file reads all the data associated with that ID and displays it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteRule script[\d]+\/[\d]+ /script$1/display.php?id=$2
```

This would rewrite anything like `script345987/22352` to `script345987/display.php?id=22352`

**Edit** if you want to match anything, not only `script`, then:

```
RewriteRule (.*)\/[\d]+ /$1/display.php?id=$2
```

Comment: `script1` and `script2` are just examples. They may also be called `bananna`, `potato` or `car` for example. I think I need to find a way to redirect anything after the second `/` to the `display.php` file of the subfolder after the first '/`.

Comment: I think I can use it like this:

`RewriteRule [\d]+\/[\d]+ /$1/display.php?id=$2`

Can I?

Comment: @Sergiu nah, [\d]+ matches numbers, i.e. **d**igits. Check the edit.